# Erlang ChicagoBoss passing url get parameters

Tags: erlang, chicagoboss, erlangweb

I would like to perform a simple operation that takes me hours to solve in erlang and ChicagoBoss:

Here is the url:
http://example.com?string=some+string

Desired result:

**some string**

/controllers/index/example_index_controllers.erl

```
-module(example_index_controller, [Req, SessionID]).
-compile([export_all]).
index('GET', []) ->
Parameter = Req:query_param("string"),
{ok, [{data, Parameter  }]}.
```

result:
/views/index/index.html

```
<b>{{ data }}</b>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Check what you're getting in RequestBody

```
RequestBody = string:tokens(binary_to_list(Req:request_body()), "&")
```